# Store browser width value into translateZ using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transform

I am basically trying to build a 3D Cube and having trouble with the translateZ property. I want to get the width of the browser and store it into the translateZ for a particular element. This will create the 3D cube responsive even when the browser is being re-sized. I want it to store the value as it works with the .auto-size

```
resizeDiv();

        window.onresize = function(event) {
            resizeDiv();
        }
        function resizeDiv() {
            vpw = $(window).width();
            vph = $(window).height();
            $('.auto-size').css({'height': vph + 'px', 'width': vpw + 'px'});
            $('.full-z').css({'transform': 'translateZ' ( vpw + 'px' ); });
        }
```

The translateZ value is given to a css class so i can use that multiple times for different divs. My markup is as follows

```
<div class="viewport">
    <div class="cube">
        <div class="cube-side1 auto-size cube-face" id="front">
        </div>
        <div class="cube-side2 auto-size cube-face full-z" id="back">
        </div>
        <div class="cube-side3 auto-size cube-face" id="left">
        </div>
        <div class="cube-side4 auto-size cube-face" id="right">
        </div>
        <div class="cube-side5 auto-size cube-face" id="top">
        </div>
        <div class="cube-side6 auto-size cube-face" id="bottom">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works with the widths and heights but not with the transform property. I have very little knowledge of jQuery.

Comment: Do you have a working example? Also, did you use the CSS property `perspective`?  `translateZ` won't appear to have an effect without it.

Comment: I did use the perspective property in css.